# Is it possible to use python multi-threading to read number of files from number of folders and process those files to get combined result?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I have to parse number of log files from number of folders and I want to speed up the parsing of those log files. I have to find some specific strings from lines of  all of those files to get final statistics in the combined form. I am not sure how I can achieve this using python multi-threading and how efficient it is. I went through different tutorials but it is not clear how file handling will be performed in case of variable files in multi threading. Any suggestion on this would be great. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well the easiest way to learn to use threading I think is using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class in `concurrent.futures` module, since it's just a couple more lines than the usual synchronous for-loop. Especially with Python 3, but this can be adapted to Python 2.7.

Basically you have a pool (bunch) of threads just waiting for work. Work is usually just a method/function which you send to the pool along with parameters and the `ThreadPool` handles everything else (assigning tasks to the available resources and scheduling).

Let's say my log directory structure is like so:

```
~ ❯ tree log
log
├── 1.log
├── 2.log
├── 3.log
└── schedules
    ├── 1.log
    ├── 2.log
    └── 3.log

1 directory, 6 files
```

So first you get your list of files (Python 3).

```
import glob
list_of_files = list(glob.iglob('log/**/*.log', recursive=True))
```

Each file (just a string variable right now) is what you want a thread to work on. So, you have a generic method, accepting a file parameter, to find the interesting string in each file. Basically the same if you did a normal Python program for, like so:

```
def find_string(file):
    # insert your specific code to find your string
    # including opening the file and such
    # returning values also possible see further down
    print(file)
```

So now you just have to send these pieces of work to the to the `ThreadPool`.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # Basically the same as if you did the normal for-loop
    for file in list_of_files:
        # But you submit your method to the Pool instead.
        future = executor.submit(find_string, file) # see future.result() too

    print("All tasks complete")
```

There's a good full example [here](https://pythonhosted.org/futures/), search for `ThreadPoolExecutor Example`, which does opens a list of Websites and prints the size in bytes. Which you could modify into file searching.

The bottle-neck you might have here, is with an enormous amount of files, would be the disk read speed. If you had the log files over multiple disks would be a solution then.

Another recommendation is that multithreading is usually used for network operations or I/O. So reading files is a good use. However, your also doing some processing. Depending on how CPU intensive it is, you might want to look at `ProcessPoolExecutor` for that which uses the `multiprocessing` module. Which shares the same interface as the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I will look into it.